# WPF bind enum to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, combobox

In my WPF `UserControl` I need to bind an `Enum` on a `ComboBox`. This `enum` is declared locally:

```
public partial class ViewerDataConfiguration : UserControl
{
    private ViewerDataConfigurationViewModel PageViewModel;
    public Visibility IsParametriSelected { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<eDatoAlarmMode> EnumAlarmModes {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(eDatoAlarmMode)).Cast<eDatoAlarmMode>();
        }
    }
```

On the main `Grid`, where there is a collection bound, I defined a `ComboBox` as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="16" Text="{Binding ConfigObject.Edit.Source}" Style="{StaticResource txtDataStyle2}" Width="30" Visibility="{Binding ConfigObject.Edit, Converter={StaticResource ListaValoriVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextChanged="Data_TextChanged" />
<Label Grid.Column="17" Content="AlarmMode" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle2}" />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="18" Width="30"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumAlarmModes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ViewerDataConfiguration}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedValuePath="Value" Style="{StaticResource comboUsersStyle}" />
```

Basically seems that my `IEnumerable` is not bound correctly. I see the elements but they're blank. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` attributes, but your collection item type is just a simple string, and want to use this entire instance directly, so you should remove these attributes and it should work as expected.

You also need to change the field to a property as data binding works only on properties, not class fields (although `x:Bind` in UWP no longer has this limitation):

```
  public IEnumerable<AlarmMode> EnumAlarmModes
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlarmMode)).Cast<AlarmMode>();
        }
    }
```

If you want to display enum values instead of names, create a value converter:

```
public class EnumValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then use it in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="18" Width="100"

    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumAlarmModes}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <local:EnumValueConverter x:Key="EnumValueConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumValueConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>     
</ComboBox>
```

For this to work you also have to add a `xmlns:local` declaration to your `Window`:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfConverter"
```

Comment: I slightly modified the code, as in effect a IEnumerable of string is not usefu as I need to bind name and value in the combobox. So the property now is:

        public IEnumerable<eDatoAlarmMode> EnumAlarmModes {
            get
            {
                return Enum.GetValues(typeof(eDatoAlarmMode)).Cast<eDatoAlarmMode>();
            }
        }

And I restored the 

                          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                          SelectedValuePath="Name"

Comment: Nope... my enum contains 3 items, I only see 3 empty items binded in the combobox

Comment: Remove the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` attributes, it works well without them.

Comment: Also if you want to display enum value instead of name, I have updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Awesome :-) . Happy coding!